# PayPal - Full HTML payment form

Tags: html, forms, paypal, payment

I've searched around the internet for at full paypal form. What i mean by this, is a form where you fill ind credit card information and stuff like thatk, and when you click the submit button, it goes to paypal and performs the payment.

I've found this form so far, but it dosn't have any credit card fields:
http://pastebin.com/1UbTanGk

Answer (score 0):

Check out this basic [credit card form I put together for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-payments-pro-php-virtual-terminal-pos/) years ago.  It's a basic shell, but it's fully functional and useful.

It does require [Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) in order to use it, though.